# What are flutter repositories

Tags: flutter, repository

I am coming from react. I am reading about repositories but can't get it quite well.

Is it something like redux store? Is there any equivalent in react that can help understand it.

Thank you

Comment: if you mean the design pattern, no it has nothing to do with react actually, its usually a layer between the DAO and the business logic classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A repository is nothing flutter specific. It's a [design pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) with many implementations in many languages.

> [A repository m]ediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

It can be used for state, but it is more generally for data. That can be user data or reference data or any other kind that you want to persist.

Comment: Is it like local storage?

Comment: It's a *concept*. Your backing store can be anything you pick.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of libraries that will help you separate business logic and UI and also help you implement reactive programming. If you know Redux from React you can take a look at these packages, especially [redux](https://pub.dev/packages?q=redux) for flutter and implement it inside your app. Other options might be [mobX](https://pub.dev/packages?q=mobx) or library created by google especially for flutter with name [BloC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted). And in the end, if you looking for something different, that combine most of the good stuff from all of those solutions and add some more to the bucket, i recommend you to take a look at package called [flutter_control](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_control).